# C# Observable Collection LDAP Paths Children for WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory, treeview

I'm hoping someone can help. A long time windows forms/aspx user, moving to WPF.

Not expecting a coded answer to this, but any pointers on a different way to approach would be greatly appreciated - I am probably approaching this in a very backward way.

So the objective is to have an ObservableCollection with sub ObservableCollection "childen" within to then bind to my WPF treeview control.

I can bind my collection to the treeview without issues, and have styled it with checkboxes images as desired, frustratingly, its the ObservableCollection with children of children of children I am having trouble generating in the first place.

I have a table in SQL with LDAP Paths, and various other information I'm storing against that LDAP path, which I read into my ObservableCollection.

Single level, no problem, the bit I'm struggling with is sorted the sub objects of sub objects by LDAP Path, so when I bind to the treeview is presented as AD OU's are structured.

EG:

- TopOU

  - Users

    - Front Office Users
    - Helpdesk Users

Example LDAP Paths in my DB

LDAP://OU=Front Office Users,OU=Users,OU=TopOU,DC=dev,DC=local

LDAP://OU=Helpdesk Users,OU=Users,OU=TopOU,DC=dev,DC=local

LDAP://OU=OU=Users,OU=TopOU,DC=dev,DC=local

LDAP://OU=OU=TopOU,DC=dev,DC=local

```
private ObservableCollection<AssignmentData> OUTreeAssignmentsCollection = new ObservableCollection<AssignmentData>();

public class AssignmentData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public Int32 AssignmentID { get; set; }
        public String AssignmentName { get; set; }
        public AssignmentTypes AssignmentType { get; set; }
        //other stuff....

        //For TreeView all sub nodes
        public ObservableCollection<AssignmentData> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I then start to read from my db in a rather nasty way, and this is where it all goes wrong, and I could use some pointers.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserGroups.UserGroupID, UserGroups.Name, UserGroups.LDAPPath FROM UserGroups WHERE UserGroups.TypeID=1", DBCon);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                String strLDAPHierarchical = GetLDAPHierarchical(reader[2].ToString());
                AssignmentData newItem = new AssignmentData()
                        {
                            AssignmentID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                            AssignmentName = reader[1].ToString(),
                            AssignmentImage = ouIcon,
                            AssignmentLDAPPath = reader[2].ToString(),
                            AssignmentCNPath = GetCNFromLDAPPath(reader[2].ToString()),
                            AssignmentTooltip = GetADSLocationTooltip(reader[2].ToString()),
                            AssignmentType = AssignmentTypes.UserOU,
                            AssignmentLDAPHierarchical = strLDAPHierarchical
                        };


                if (strLDAPHierarchical.Contains(","))
                {
                    //Now check all the root nodes exist to continue
                    String strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath = strLDAPHierarchical;
                    String[] SplitLDAPHierarchical = strLDAPHierarchical.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

                    Int32 reverseI = SplitLDAPHierarchical.Length - 1;
                    String prevPath = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < SplitLDAPHierarchical.Length; i++)
                    {
                        String path = SplitLDAPHierarchical[reverseI];
                        //now check if this node is already there and if not look it up and create it
                        if (path != "")
                        {
                            if (i == 0) { strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath = path; }
                            else { strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath = path + "," + prevPath; }
                            WriteLog("CHECK:" + strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath);
                            LookupItemByLDAPHierarchical(strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath, newItem);

                            if (i == 0) { prevPath = path; }
                            else { prevPath = path + "," + prevPath; }
                            reverseI = reverseI - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //is top level object, so create at the root of the collection
                    UserOUCollection.Add(newItem);
                }
```

Function to add sub items :-/

```
internal AssignmentData LookupItemByLDAPHierarchical(String strLDAPHierarchical, AssignmentData fromItem)
    {
        AssignmentData currentItem = null;
        foreach (AssignmentData d in UserOUCollection)
        {

            if (d.AssignmentLDAPHierarchical == strLDAPHierarchical) { currentItem = d; break; }
            if (d.Children != null)
            {
                currentItem = CheckChildNodesByLDAPHierarchical(d, strLDAPHierarchical);
                if (currentItem != null) { break; }
            }
        }

        String strMessage = "null";
        if (currentItem != null) { strMessage = currentItem.AssignmentLDAPPath; }

        if (currentItem == null) 
        {
            String strWhere = "LDAPPath LIKE 'LDAP://" + strLDAPHierarchical + "%'";

            SqlConnection DBCon = new SqlConnection(SQLString);
            DBCon.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserGroupID, Name, LDAPPath FROM UserGroups WHERE " + strWhere + " AND TypeID=1", DBCon);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                strLDAPHierarchical = GetLDAPHierarchical(reader[2].ToString());
                AssignmentData newItem = new AssignmentData()
                {
                    AssignmentID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                    AssignmentName = reader[1].ToString(),
                    AssignmentImage = ouIcon,
                    AssignmentLDAPPath = reader[2].ToString(),
                    AssignmentCNPath = GetCNFromLDAPPath(reader[2].ToString()),
                    AssignmentTooltip = GetADSLocationTooltip(reader[2].ToString()),
                    AssignmentType = AssignmentTypes.UserOU,
                    AssignmentLDAPHierarchical = strLDAPHierarchical
                };

                    String strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath = strLDAPHierarchical;
                    foreach (String path in strLDAPHierarchical.Split(new Char[] { ',' }))
                    {
                        //now check if this node is already there and if not look it up and create it
                        if (path != "")
                        {
                            strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath = strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath.Replace(path + ",", "");
                            currentItem = LookupItemByLDAPHierarchical(strLDAPHierarchicalCheckPath, currentItem);

                            if (null == currentItem)
                            {
                                UserOUCollection.Add(newItem); //new root item
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (currentItem.Children == null)
                                {
                                    //add new child
                                    currentItem.Children = new ObservableCollection<AssignmentData> { newItem };
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //add more children to exisiting
                                    currentItem.Children.Add(newItem);
                                }
                            }
                            currentItem = null;
                        }
                    }

                //Find a current Item to add the node to
                //currentItem = LookupItemByLDAPHierarchical(strLDAPHierarchical);

            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();

            DBCon.Close();
            DBCon.Dispose();


        }

        return currentItem;
    }
```

With my current solution, I get a treeview, with sub nodes of sub nodes, but they are wrong/lots of duplication etc. I have spent literally days trying to fix my probably overcomplicated attempt above - but have come to the conclusion I'm probably going about it the wrong way.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having a peruse ;) through your code. Think I can see why you have lots of duplications. Looks like your first SQL query get's **all** parent/child records. Then the second query will go and get some of those records again, if that makes sense.

One approach would be to only get the top level items in your first query. Possibly by getting SQL to count the number of commas.

```
SELECT UserGroups.UserGroupID, UserGroups.Name, UserGroups.LDAPPath, 
       LENGTH(LDAPPath) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LDAPPath, ',', '')) as CommaCount 
FROM UserGroups 
WHERE UserGroups.TypeID=1 
  AND CommaCount = 2
```

Since you asked for different approach id say it's not very efficient to repeatedly query the database in a loop. When I'm building a tree of parent child objects I'd normally get all parent/child records in one query. Build a flat dictionary of all the objects. Then loop through it and make the parent/child associations.

The dictionary can also be useful to lookup your objects later on either directly by key or to loop through without having to make a recursive function that crawls the tree.

So I'd suggest that you break it down into 2 blocks of code.

**First block:** Using your existing query that get's **all** of the items, create a flat Dictionary with everything in.

They key of each item should probably be the result from GetLDAPHierarchical().

**Second block:** Next loop through the dictionary and create the hierarchy. Add anything with no parent directly to the UserOUCollection

```
foreach(AssignmentData d in myDictionary.Values)
{
    String parentKey = GetParentLDAPKey(d.AssignmentLDAPHierarchical);

    if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(parentKey))
    {
        myDictionary(parentKey).children.Add(d);
    }
    else
    {
        UserOUCollection.Add(d);
    }
}
```

**GetParentLDAPKey()** will need to produce the same key as it's parent by removing the first part of the LDAP Path.

Hope that points you in the right direction.

H

(SMASH)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much to hman, who pointed me in a much more logical direction. I used LDAPPath as my dictionary key.

```
Dictionary<String, AssignmentData> OUDictionary = new Dictionary<String, AssignmentData>();

//Read from DB
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserGroups.UserGroupID, UserGroups.Name, UserGroups.LDAPPath FROM UserGroups WHERE UserGroups.TypeID=1", DBCon);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                AssignmentData newItem = new AssignmentData()
                        {
                            AssignmentID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                            AssignmentName = reader[1].ToString(),
                            AssignmentImage = ouIcon,
                            AssignmentLDAPPath = reader[2].ToString(),
                            AssignmentCNPath = GetCNFromLDAPPath(reader[2].ToString()),
                            AssignmentTooltip = GetADSLocationTooltip(reader[2].ToString()),
                            AssignmentType = AssignmentTypes.UserOU,
                        };
                UserOUDictionary.Add(reader[2].ToString(), newItem);

            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();


            //Now Read OU List into TreeView Collection
            foreach (AssignmentData d in UserOUDictionary.Values)
            {
                String parentKey = GetParentLDAPPath(d.AssignmentLDAPPath);
                if (UserOUDictionary.ContainsKey(parentKey))
                {
                    AssignmentData parentItem = UserOUDictionary[parentKey];
                    if (parentItem.Children == null) { parentItem.Children = new ObservableCollection<AssignmentData> { d }; } //add first child
                    else { parentItem.Children.Add(d); } //add more children to exisiting
                }
                else
                {
                    UserOUCollection.Add(d); //add to root of control
                }
            }


private String GetParentLDAPKey(String strLDAPPath)
    {
        String retParentKey = strLDAPPath;
        if (strLDAPPath.Contains(","))
        {
            retParentKey = retParentKey.Replace("LDAP://", "");
            retParentKey = retParentKey.Remove(0, retParentKey.IndexOf(",") + 1);
            retParentKey = "LDAP://" + retParentKey;
        }

        return retParentKey;
    }
```